# Using local DB copy for EF - "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm attempting to create a copy of a database schema, and then use it in the application temporarily for testing purposes so I don't alter live data. However, no matter what I do, it always gives me this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

I have tried making my connection strings look like the following:

```
<add name="EntitiesConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\vipertest.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="EntitiesConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\vipertest.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I've tried with an mdf file, and without.

I've done this in both Web.Config and app.config, but I always get the same error.

Comment: Your connection string doesn't in fact look like an Entity Framework connection string. Posted an answer that might help explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework connection strings don't typically look like either of the strings you're showing. Your connection string looks like a plain sql server connection string.

An EF connection string typically contains EF metadata. Here is an example from one of my EF connection strings:

So you're connection string may look somewhat different, but it should contain entity metadata references, etc.

I would start with the actual connection string being used in production (if you can get it), even sanitized, and then modify it accordingly.

[This MSDN article on EF connection strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx) might help.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I didn't think about that - I will go try it out :)

Comment: It worked! I've marked your response as the answer - thank you!

What I did was take the connection string with meta data in it from production like you said, and then just replaced the connection string section with the first connection string I have as an example in the question.

Comment: Glad that helped you.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error that says "The underlying provider failed on Open." when I'm attempting to actually access the data.

Comment: Hmm, it might be easier to post this as a different question with your new connection strings, any relevant code, etc. and I can take a look.

Comment: Yeah, I agree - I posted one recently with the details; thank you for taking the time!

Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610948/localdb-error-when-accessing-data-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open